# Capturing image from WebCam in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, webcam

I'm developing an app in .Net Core 2.0 to run on a Raspberry Pi, which is running Win 10 IoT. The Pi has a USB WebCam attached and I'm looking to capture a still image from the camera. Unfortunately this is proving somewhat troublesome, to say the least.

Firstly I had a good search through the .Net Core 2.0 libraries to see if there's anything that will provide this functionality, but have not had any luck.

My second line of enquiry was NuGet, to see if any third-party libraries might do the job. EmguCV looked promising for a while, but they do not seem to support .Net Core just yet.

Finally I googled for anything that might do the job and came across the MediaCapture class in Windows.Media.Capture for UWP, but I've had no success referencing this from my .Net Core console app. It seems like you can reference .Net Core assemblies from UWP solutions, but I've not found a way to do it the other way around.

Bearing in mind that I'd prefer to keep my project in .Net Core 2.0, rather than re-writing for UWP, I'm looking for any means of capturing a still image from the WebCam. Any pointers will be gratefully received, as this is proving to be surprisingly frustrating.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For capturing images and other image processing activities, probably you can try **OpenCvSharp**.

It has support for .NET Core.

https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp

***NuGet Packages*** are available (look for more details in the above link on the correct one(s) to choose).

Here is an example for capturing video:

https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_samples/tree/master/CameraOpenCV

if you pass 0 (zero) as input to `VideoCapture`, it should open the default camera.

Something like this (not tried):

```
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0); //assumption based on how actual openCV works.
```

Comment: @WojtekTurowicz I guess you solved this already, but there is a nuget package that add all the required dlls into your project for a specific runtime. I had to add the windows runtime package to get OpenCvSharp to work on my PC

Answer (score 0):

You can reference universal windows app's core libraries (Windows.Media.winmd,  Windows.Security.winmd, etc...) on any dot net application (core, framework, standard). I have done it. However, the 'await' will be all messed up so you will have to deal with work around to use await and async (i.e. manually waiting for the task).

Windows.Media has the Microsoft's api to talk to the camera.

I am not sure if universal apps work on a Raspberry Pi thou.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Win 10 IoT on Raspberry try using "Intelligent Kiosk" sample program available in Git by Microsoft. It gives a UWP app (Source Code) which has a good camera control with more options to customize. This is C#.  If you want VB version you can ping me.

The IK code does many more things using Azure Cognitive services which may be of interest to you.

Comment: will IK support MAUI.NET ?

Comment: MAUI.NET is C# only (no VB) and so i did not go that way. Sorry. But MAUI.NET is a device/OS independent client framework. So the IK related core functionality which can be implemented over WebAPI can be consumed from MAUI.NET client app. Hope that helps.